# Running sub shell command in Ansible ad-hoc

Tags: bash, ansible

I would like to run a sub shell command in an ad-hoc Ansible command.

Here is what I want to do :

```
sudo ansible myservers -m shell -a "touch /var/tmp/$(uname -n)"
```

It creates the remote file but with the name of the local host, it doesn't execute the uname command on remote servers.

Comment: Well, someone deleted the tag ansible, I don't know why...

Comment: I've added the Ansible tag again...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
sudo ansible myservers -m shell -a '/bin/bash -c "toto=`uname -n` ; touch /var/tmp/\$toto.json;"'
```

Seems that I have to start a shell to execute sub shell commands, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the double-quotes in your command.
They mean that the content between the double-quotes (including your `$(...)`) will be interpreted by the shell that executes this command (your Ansible control node), so you get the ansible control node name.

If you replace the double-quotes with simple-quotes, the shell of the control node will not interpret the content, and will pass it "as-is" to the ansible hosts. Afterwards, these ansible hosts will interpret the `$(...)`, so you'll get the target ansible hostname.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html

So it could be fixed with :

```
ansible myservers -m shell -a 'touch /var/tmp/$(uname -n)'
```

(I don't see why you had to use `sudo`)

Or (if the name of your host in your inventory is good enough), you could use :

```
ansible myservers -m shell -a 'touch /var/tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}'
```

By the way, if you end-up using this command in a playbook, another solution is to use the Ansible facts : `ansible_hostname` or `ansible_fqdn` for example